# Dropdown options are not wrapped in mozilla firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I am facing a issue in which i am binding a dropdownlist in the last column of my table which contains options with large text, in the mozilla firefox i am not able to see the whole content. Some content is hidden, please suggest me some css tricks to resolve the issue.

```
<select id="1171 ,985" class="form-control ddlActionList">

     <option value="">-- Auswählen --</option>
     <option value="11213" style="color: Red;">Zubuchen : [Blist - 6135310] - ALDACTONE 25 überzogene Tabletten 100 St (43,000)</option>
     <option value="46" selected="selected" style="color: Red;">Zubuchen : [Blist - 2227104] - CARVEDILOL HEXAL 12,5 mg Tabletten 100 St (88,000)</option>
     <option value="1403" style="color: Red;">Zubuchen : [Blist - 3568238] - FUROSEMID ratiopharm 40 mg Tabletten 100 St (13,000)</option>
     <option value="1867" style="color: Red;">Zubuchen : [Blist - 6444040] - NOVAMINSULFON 500 1A Pharma Filmtabletten 50 St (26,000)</option>
     <option value="1161" style="color: Red;">Zubuchen : [5046975] PANTOPRAZOL 1A Pharma 20 mg magensaftres.Tabletten 100 St (10,000)</option>
     <option value="11215" style="color: Red;">Zubuchen : [Blist - 5003919] - VITAMIN B Komplex forte Hevert Tabletten 50 St (29,000)</option>
     <option value="2086" style="color: Red;">Zubuchen : [Blist - 4369475] - XARELTO 15 mg Filmtabletten 98 St (91,000)</option>
     <option value="-4" style="color: Red;">ignoriere Import</option>
     <option value="-3" style="color: Red;">bereits importiert</option>
     <option value="-1" style="color: Red;">keine Aktion</option>

</select>
```

[image: Dropdown list text not wrapped in firefox]

Comment: Did you try something like `overflow-y: scroll;` this should allow you to scroll through the options.

Comment: could you post the CSS for `form-control ddlActionList`?

Comment: .form-control {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset;
    color: #8d8d8d;
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 34px;
    line-height: 1.42857;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out 0s, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out 0s;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
}

Comment: overflow-y: scroll; is not working